# Changing localhost to my machine name in the request url in jquery does not work

Tags: jquery, wcf

I have a WCF service that works fine on my local machine, and a client that uses AJAX from jQuery, everything is working fine locally using localhost in the url, I tried to replace localhost with my machine name, and run again locally, but the request does not work and causes error in the response of the calback function in js.

The response does not hold any meaning information (readystate = 4, error)

Comment: What is your machine name and does it contain for instance a hyphen?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 7):

It could be that you are violating [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Have you tried changing the URL in browser to your machine name as well?

On another note, since you can, normally, only do AJAX calls on the same host, you should simply use relative paths over absolute paths, e.g. `/foo/bar?key=val` instead of `http://localhost/foo/bar?key=val`.

Comment: What I meant was, if in browser you enter `http://yourhost/...` to bring up the app, you should have `http://yourhost/...` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not perfectly sure, but this seems like a problem in your service.
It sounds like your service ist bound to localhost, resp. to the IP 127.0.0.1.

If you want to access it via your LAN IP address, just make sure, the service is bount to it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I understood this, but I remember these kind of issues from webserver configuration. You are able to bin a specific vhost to the IP address 127.0.0.1. If you now try to access this vhost via your LAN IP e.g. 192.168.1.12, the connection fails, as the server is listening on the local interface. On the other hand, as William Niu said, a SOP issue is possible too. Could you perhaps add some information about server and client network, the URIs you send the requests to or the JS code?

Answer (score 1):

use IP address of your system instead of mahcine name.